# Need help updating Ubuntu with apt-offline

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, offline

I have a build of Ubuntu 12.04LTS that needs to be kept "quarantined", so no connection to the internet and all new software, data etc must be passed through a number of security checks before being installed.

I am 100% new to Ubuntu and have been trying to find a way to perform updates offline. I am happy to take any advice on which way is best but decided to use the apt-offline route as the process seemed the simplest! (I have tried to use Keryx as well but with no luck! The application loaded and searched for packages but did not go further.)

Using apt-offline I have created the signature file, transferred the file to an internet connected machine, downloaded the packages and moved them back to the quarantined machine (134mb of them). I then run the `apt-offline install` command and the terminal seems to do what it should and install the updates.

To check the status of required updates, I look in details and press the "check for updates" and there are still the same amount of updates required than when I started the process (428 required updates, I am fairly sure this build of Ubuntu has never been connected to the internet and never received any updates) Also, I really only require the Security Updates, the recommended updates are not needed/wanted!

I can run `apt-get --just-print upgrade` in terminal and it returns a bunch of required updates.

I think I am following the instructions for `apt-offline` but the packages don't seem to be installing with `apt-offline install {path_to_packages}`, can anyone provide any advice as to what I have missed or done wrong?

Comment: can we make short n simple ?

Comment: Short n simple version.....
Apt-offline seems to downloading update packages but not installing them, can anyone help!? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm would recommend you this post: 
http://cartaslinux.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/apt-offline/

It works very well for me with those steps.